# Motion open string

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, string-theory, boundary-conditions, branes

In the introduction book of Zwiebach, he mentions in chapter 6 that the endpoints of an open string move with the speed of light. First, I assume he means in the longitudinal direction. But then, worldsheets traced by open strings aren't drawn with 45 angles (light-like world lines) in Minkoswki space.

Besides, the width of such worldsheet also changes along the path, isn't that in contrast with Dirichlet boundary conditions which states that the end points are held fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Zwiebach is in section 6.9 talking about open strings in the static gauge (6.62) with free endpoint conditions (6.56), aka. Neumann BC, not Dirichlet BC (6.55). In other words, if there is a D-brane, it should be space-filling. Such endpoints move with the speed of light transversely to the string.

On the other hand, Dirichlet BC is discussed in problem 6.11.